# Find all hidden files that were hidden using the command "chflags hidden filename"?

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos

I remember to hide an important file, but I can't find it anymore and I don't remember the name. I don't remember how I hid it, i.e., if just by inserting a prefix of `.` or using `chflags hidden filename`.

I tried to recover all hidden files (hidden because of the prefix `.`) under my desktop using the following command

```
find . -name '.*' | grep "^.DS_Store" > hidden-files.txt
```

and the resulting `hidden-files.txt` text file is empty. (Anyway, I'm not 100% sure if the command above is correct.)

Again, now I would like to retrieve recursively (as I'm doing with the previous command) all hidden files that were hidden using the command `chflags hidden filename` using the terminal (or without, but I would need to have a list of them or a path to them). Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

**Edit 1**

I think the command above doesn't work because `grep` does not accept input. Anyway, to solve the problem I think I just need to add `xargs` as follows

```
find . -name '.*' | xargs grep "^.DS_Store" > hidden-files.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you

```
find . ! -name '.' \( -name '.*' -o -flags hidden \)
```

which means find in the current directory, all file system objects, except do not list the current working directory- (`! -name '.'`), whose name begins with a dot or file flag is set to hidden.